# Fetching site's every page with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

For example I got site.com with /page1, /page2 and /page3 pages. I need fetch site's every page, but when I'm using `UrlFetchApp.fetch('site.com')` it's only fetches the main page. Is there exists any possible way to say to *UrlFetchApp* to fetch every page without specifying particular page?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No its not possible. There is no way to enumerate your pages or site structure.
This is not psrticular to gas. You would need to do a web crawler and urlFetchApp wont help you for that.
Your options are:
1) if its a google site use the sites api.
2) else maybe maintain a file in root with the list of all pages. Fetch that snd use it to loop through all. You only have 6min. to do it from gas unless you break it into tasks (with time trigger)

Comment: That has nothing to do with apps script.